# Can't change a fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm trying to change a fragment inside a ViewPager:

```
public void change() {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.pager, mapa);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

R.id.pager is my ViewPager id.
mapa is a inflated fragment.
If I call change(), the fragment I want to replace will disappear but the new fragment will not be load.

Answer (score -1):

The view pager uses an Adapter to change the fragments it displays. Just like a ListView uses its adapter to get views to populate the list.

You have to extend [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), create a new instance of it and set it to the pager with this line:

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(fragPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Eclipse do it for me when i create the Tabs+swipe+title strip activity...
are u talking about this?
// Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
// primary sections of the app.
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

Comment: yes. that's the one. Check the documentations that there're a lot of nicely explained examples.

Comment: i dont understand you... my problem isn´t about the adapter, i did the implementation and works fine. My problem is only when i try to replace one fragment, because it only removes the old one but dont load the new one.

Comment: What your code is trying to do is to replace any views inside the viewpager to `mapa`. But the ViewPager was never meant to be used as a normal ViewGroup. This type of operation is only for normal ViewGroups such as FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout. The only way to use ViewPagers is through the use of adapters.